# How to create long live connection between background Js to popup Js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am trying to call the popup Js when background Js gets any new message from my client server through socket Io.
But here I am getting this error on background page.

```
Uncaught Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object
```

**Background.js**

```
var socket = null;

function clickHandler(e) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
        port = chrome.tabs.connect(tabs[0].id, {name: "szWhatsApp"});
        callback(port);
    });
}

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {

    port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
        console.log("message recieved " + msg);
        socket.emit('message-status', msg);
    });

    socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3003');
    socket.on('message-new', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        port.postMessage({from:'szWhatsAppBot', action: 'newMsg',data: data});
    });
});
```

**Popup.js**

```
var port = chrome.extension.connect({
    name: "SZ-WhatsApp"
});

port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
    document.getElementById("message").textContent = "recieved " + msg;
});

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
    port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
        port.postMessage("I get it.");
    });
});
```

**Client.js**

```
// Listen for messages from the popup
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, response) {
    console.log(msg);

    return true;
});

function clearTimer() {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
}
```

Comment: Does it happens after the popup has been closed?

Comment: @wOxxOm ya if I switch tabs then it throws error in background page

Comment: The toolbar popup is destroyed when it's closed and recreated when shown.

Comment: @wOxxOm How to create a port by tab name and contact that particular tab popup js when background js gets any new message.

Comment: In other words, a popup exists only when displayed after the toolbar icon is clicked. When it isn't shown, it doesn't exist, its code doesn't run, nothing in the popup exists.

Comment: @wOxxOm Is there a way to contact the client js from background js

Comment: Where does client.js run? How is it injected/declared? What is the specific reason for longlived port connection and not just usual one-time messaging? How does the popup come into the mix? We're not mind-readers, unfortunately.